# Integrate Leaflet map into PDF

Tags: leaflet, pdf, html

I am current in the process of writing a thesis. Being in the field of GIS it obviously involves some maps ;). While the whole world switched to interactive online maps, Universities still require to hand in a PDF in the end. I am wondering if there are options to integrate a Leaflet map into a PDF. So basically I want to embed a HTML into a PDF.

<sub>I also asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858064/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-html-into-a-pdf/22858321?noredirect=1#comment34874266_22858321), but being a more GIS specific on GIS Stack Exchange.</sub>

Comment: It'd be remarkable to see leaflet run in a PDF viewer, but I think you're going to be doing screenshots and a URL for the live site...

Answer (score 1):

You can embed html and run *some* javascript in PDF, but it appears that there is not enough support for Leaflet to run - there's no XmlHttpRequest which you would need to fetch your data. It might be possible with some hacking, since Adobe Javascript has its own net library, but it's not going to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't want to rely on anything dynamic for your thesis.

I would not link to a website and rely on that, and as much as possible, would ensure that the PDF stands on its own as a final document. Don't forget that (I think) you will be assessed on a bound version.

What I would do is set up your maps to be perfect for a print document, which means ensuring label fonts, map size, scale and all the marginalia are appropriate for print. That's your target. Then perhaps include an appendix or reference to support material that could include interactive mapping, that's just a bonus.

If you are really committed, there are ways you can do [GIS-ish mapping in a PDF](http://www.neurisa.org/resources/Documents/NEURISA-Low-Cost-PDF-Maps.pdf), and you can do [3D maps in a PDF](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#pdf/pdf.htm). But it's not very standard and, I think, very gimmicky.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take screenshots of the map, and cite the screen shots with a link to a live, working map. Be sure to put the map at some URL that won't change for a long time.

An interactive map is an external resource, and does not need to/should not be embedded or otherwise added to a print document. Cite it as you would any other resource not translatable to print, such as a movie.